# Storing encryption keys in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption

Search results show me that a lot of questions about "where/how to store encryption keys of a server application" have been asked and answered. I don't think I find those answers satisfactory.

Suppose you're hosting an asp.net web application which manages some keys somewhere to protect sensitive data in the database. If I was an attacker who somehow gained access to the web server, I would just download and decompile the assembly of the .net application. Then, once I figure out what api calls the application makes to access sensitive data, I would return to the server and add an aspx page to the application. The aspx page would use the same set of apis to query the database (i.e. XyzRepository.GetAll() kind of calls). Then, my aspx page would dump the decrypted rows to disk for me. My aspx page wouldn't even care where and how the decryption takes place. Whether the web application is using DPAPI to protect its keys or not, whether it's using protected configuration or not, I would have access to the data. Because my aspx page would be running in the context of the web application (i.e. it benefits from the same application pool identity, same machine key, same everything).

When I think of this, I tend to believe that once somebody hacks into your server, they are going to get your data no matter where and how you store your keys. In that sense I found accepted answers to previous questions about the subject delusional. Am I missing something?

And, I'm wondering if there is a way to configure the IIS server so that application pool will be purged and will never be restarted as soon as a new piece of code is added to the application (i.e. code signature checking for the whole web application, all the standalone aspx pages and dlls)?

Comment: _if there is a way to configure the IIS server ..._ - and why wouldn't the hacker turn that off?

Comment: _If I was an attacker who somehow gained access to the web server_ then you have a bigger problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Security" can only be defined against a certain threat.

Most encryption based security is protecting against someone eavesdropping on your communication.

> If I was an attacker who somehow gained access to the web server, ...

That is a much more severe threat. A common protection against it is the double firewall:

Your WebServer (IIS #1) serves the public but has no access to the database. It hast to call an Application Server (IIS #2) behind the second firewall.

> The aspx page would use the same set of apis to query the database (i.e. XyzRepository.GetAll() kind of calls)

When the API has a call like that, the data is not considered secret.